# Read from "Broadcom GNSS 4752 Geolocation Sensor" with C#

Tags: c#, windows, gps, geolocation

I have Windows 10 tablet with "**Broadcom GNSS 4752 Geolocation Sensor**" displayed under Sensors node in Device Manager. I need to connect to this sensor and get location reading, then extract Latitude and Longitude points from it. How can I achieve that using C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows.Devices.Geolocation API for desktop application.

It works on windows 8/8.1/10 with installed platform localisation.

In order to access to namespace `Windows.​Devices.​Geolocation` you can set target platform version of you project to `8.1` and target framework .net to `4.5.1`.
You can do this by editing the `.csproj` file.

Example part `file.csproj` with this information about target platform.

```
<ProjectGuid>{D29050E9-B447-43DE-BA11-0CA8F402200D}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>ConsoleApplication1</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>ConsoleApplication1</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
<FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
```

When do updated the project file, you can add reference to the assembly.
Also you should add reference to `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`.

Example code how to gather position:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    myGeolocator = new Geolocator() { DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High };
    var geopositionAsyncResult = myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
    geopositionAsyncResult.Completed = GetGeopositionCompleted;
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void GetGeopositionCompleted(IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> asyncInfo, AsyncStatus asyncStatus)
{
    switch (asyncStatus)
    {
        case AsyncStatus.Completed:
            var result = asyncInfo.GetResults();
            var possition = result.Coordinate.Point.Position;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Latitude = {0} Longitude = {1}", possition.Latitude, possition.Longitude));
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine(myGeolocator.LocationStatus.ToString());
            break;
    }
}
```

In order to access use geolocation you must:
set access to the windows user settings privacy - location
set access in control panel - localisation

Answer (score 0):

Check out the UWP samples on GitHub. There's a [Geolocator sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Geolocation) that uses GPS to find your location. It looks like the [Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225537.aspx) method is the one you'll want to use for getting lat/long.

Comment: No, I know this but I need to connect to a sensor on a tablet with Windows 10 NOT WinRT. Geolocator works well on WinRT devices, like mobiles and tablets. But not on Win32 like PCs, Laptops, and some kinds of tablet.

Comment: Windows 10 uses many of the same APIs as RT. Whether it's a PC or laptop or mobile device is immaterial - if you have an attached GPS device that is recognized as such by Windows 10, the APIs referenced in the sample should work. Also, don't confuse Windows 10 with Win32.

Comment: I remember that I tried location APIs for Windows while I was developing Windows 8.1 apps, but it wasn't get location from GPS. It was getting location from WiFi and Cellular data.

Comment: If your device has no GPS functionality, Windows will use other devices to determine location. But if you have a valid GPS device, the sample noted above will use the GPS data. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx